# How to convert a byte array to string without GC_CONCURRENT

Tags: java, android

I have a function that converts a byte array of 4 bytes to a string and returns this string by using this line:

```
return new String(bytes);
```

The problem is that this function is called thousands of times per second and it causes the "GC_CONCURRENT freed ..." message to appear very often. I guess it is because of the "new String". I couldn't find alternative methods, can anyone offer one? Thanks =)

Comment: Will there be any redundancy? You could try recycling the string objects.

Comment: Your first problem is that you're using the platform default encoding, which is a really bad idea in most cases. But fundamentally, if you're creating too many strings, you need to work out how to make do with fewer. We can't really help you with that, without any more context. Do you actually have an *issue* anyway? Just because the GC says "I'm still coping - yay!" frequently doesn't mean there's necessarily anything to worry about.

Comment: I think you should include the android tag

Comment: The way to get fewer GC warnings is to use fewer strings.  For a lot of small structures that just hold values (like Point or Rect) you can reuse the object and overwrite old data, but since strings are immutable in Java that isn't really possible here.  Unless you can change your architecture to not require all of those arrays to be converted to String, you're pretty well stuck.